# Django rest framework, change ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i'm fighting with DRF too long so now i must ask question.. How change ForeignKey to another? I have user profile and relation to status model.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ldap_uid = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    redmine_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, models.SET_NULL, blank=False, null=True, default=DEFAULT_STATUS_ID)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, models.SET_NULL, blank=False, null=True, default=DEFAULT_LOCATION_ID)
    online = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class SelectValuesModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Status(SelectValuesModel):
    pass


class Location(SelectValuesModel):
    pass
```

What is good way to change Profile status to another? I'm trying with something like this without success

views.py

```
class UserStatusView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        user_profile = user.profile
        new_stauts = Status.objects.get(request.data.status)
        serialized_data = ProfileSerializer(user_profile)
        if(serialized_data.is_valid()):
            serialized_data.save(status=new_stauts)
        return Response(serialized_data.errors)
```

And trying send new id via PATCH. I'm trying tto find solution but no success here too. And how do it good? Make another route for updating Profile status? Or make something like profile/1/update_status/2? Now my routing looks like:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'redmine', views.RedmineCurrentTaskView, base_name='redmine')
router.register(r'parameters', views.ParametersView, base_name='parameters')
router.register(r'update_status', views.UserStatusView, base_name='update_status')
router.register(r'debug', views.DebugStatus, base_name='debug')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('api/', include(router.urls))
]
```

And serializers.py

```
class SelectValuesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('pk', 'name', 'display_name')


class LocationSerializer(SelectValuesSerializer):
    class Meta(SelectValuesSerializer.Meta):
        model = Location


class StatusSerializer(SelectValuesSerializer):
    class Meta(SelectValuesSerializer.Meta):
        model = Status


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = StatusSerializer()
    location = LocationSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('status', 'location', 'online', 'redmine_id')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'first_name', 'profile')
        read_only_fields = ('first_name',)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass `request.data` to the serializer with [`partial=True`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates) argument:

```
class UserStatusView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        user_profile = user.profile
        serialized_data = ProfileSerializer(user_profile, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serialized_data.is_valid():
            serialized_data.save()
            return Response(serialized_data.data)
        return Response(serialized_data.errors)
```

You need to provide status_id with request body like this:

```
{"status": 1}
```

**UPD**

To pass status as id change your serializer to this:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = LocationSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('status', 'location', 'online', 'redmine_id')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        self.fields['status'] = StatusSerializer()
        return super(ProfileSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
```

This allows to post status_id, but get status details with your API.

Comment: I tied that and always get error: {
    "status": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
        ]
    }
}

Comment: I suppose you set in serializer `status=StatusSerializer()`? You can just add it into `to_representation` method to show status details for GET request only.

Comment: @Sierran I've updated answer:) You need to add `to_representation` and remove `status = StatusSerializer()`.

Comment: Oh my god! It works! Thank you! But for future.. This is good solution? I can't find that in DRF documentation. And what is good practice to create routing?

Comment: @Sierran yes it's common practice to override `to_representation`. As for routing I suggest you to use `DefaultRouter` as you already did. Check link about to_representation method overriding: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example_1

Comment: Thanx! I know it's lame question.. But can you explain me to_representation in my example? In documentation is 100% crear for me how to use it but in my example? i don't understand difference with and without to_representation in my problem, what is difference between status = StatusSerializer() and self.fields['status'] = StatusSerializer(). And why we use super?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171392/discussion-between-neverwalkaloner-and-sierran).